# Python Input Performance

Tags: python, performance, parsing, input, io

### Background

I've been trying to brush up on my Python knowledge through the excellent challanges available on Kattis. I'm now stumped on [this problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/chopwood) which requires good efficiency. My solution gets the right answers, but too slowly. While other languages will probably be quicker, I know from the stats that it can be solved using Python 3.

### The Problem

The program is given an integer length, and then a list of that length containing integer values. I add these to a list, but when I am given very long lists, the program exceeds the 3s time limit before it finishes reading input.

Any suggestions on how to speed things up will be greatly appreciated!

### The Code So Far (updated with comprehension)...

[Gist copy](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4322dff72f6e751515e2)

```
import collections

length = int(input())
inputList = []
maxVal = 0
# Set offers O(1) when checking if an element is present.
history = set()
results = []
impossible = False

inputList = [input() for _ in range(length)]

# Map int conversion and convert to deque for O(1) removal from left later on.
# Is this worth it?
inputDeque = collections.deque(map(int, inputList))

# Find highest value. Was doing this during input,
# moved here to potentially speed up input loop.
maxVal = max(inputDeque)

# There must be a smarter way here,
# but we're not getting this far on large inputs yet.

# For every element of input,
# find the lowest value that is not in the remaining input or history.
for _ in range(length):
    for i in range(1, 200000, 1):
        # If the lowest value we can get is higher than the largest input, this can't be solved.
        if i >= maxVal:
            impossible = True
            break
        if i not in history and i not in inputDeque:
            results.append(i)
            history.add(i)
            inputDeque.popleft()
            break
    if impossible:
        break

if impossible:
    print('Error')
else:
    [print(i) for i in results]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: why not printing/formatting the results later and use a list instead of adding to a string? strings are immutable, python needs to create a new object for each element (and concatenate the values)

Comment: @Pynchia Good point! I'll do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try using a list comprehension to receive the input:

```
nums = [input() for i in range(length)]
```

A list comprehension is generally faster than appending to a list using a for loop. Look here for some info on different speeds, with different looping methods, https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops

Comment: That link is really helpful, thanks. I've moved to using a list comprehension now; although I've still not cracked that 3 second limit to read 200,000 lines of input.

Comment: perhaps a generator would help make things faster. Though, by the sounds of things, maybe the whole program could do with a few optimisations here and there. I'm going to have a look at it myself also.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a list comprehension. Appending requires that the method is looked up at every turn, whereas list comprehensions are much more optimized:

```
inputList = [input() for _ in range(length)]
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, cheers. I've moved to using the list comprehension in the input, and will look at improving the other loops too. Still running into the time limit on input even with this change.